# React native Redux - object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new ctor(props context)')

Tags: react-native, react-redux

This is a very simple page that is trying to use Redux....see code below.

However Im getting the error `object is not a constructor (evaluating 'new ctor(props context)')`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  userId: state.auth.userId,
});

class Message extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Text here</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null,
)(Message);
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Reset cache work for me:

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Other solution is use `createSwitchNavigator` instead `createStackNavigator`, in your navigator container.

Comment: super interesting..I ran into this error today after connecting a simple class component to Redux and was going nuts trying to figure out what I did wrong. Simple restart of expo server in the terminal resolved. Thanks!

Comment: `yarn cache clean` did the trick for me. Expo will need some time to build the app again.

Answer (score 3):

for the yarn user, I tried this, totally works

```
yarn cache clean
```

Answer (score 1):

Restarting the builder works..