# Why I'm getting "ctor is not a constructor" in react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using redux for my react application to manage all the global states. So I have created some multiple reducers because our application is large scale application. So all our components are connected with redux store.

But I'm getting this **"ctor is not a constructor"** error message randomly on page refresh or moving across components. I really don't know the root cause of this issue. Sometimes the error message will come and sometimes it won't.

> I'm new to redux, so I have written code as per the documentation and tutorials available on the internet

Here is the sample code I wrote to connect a component to redux

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    subject_name: state.content.subject_name,
    chapter_name: state.content.chapter_name,
    quiz_name: state.content.quiz_name,
});

class Quiz extends Component {

// this is here my component code will be...

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Quiz);
```

And this is the error message i'm getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: ctor is not a constructor
    at constructClassInstance (react-dom.development.js:12709)
    at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17425)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19073)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293)
    at react-dom.development.js:11327
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:646)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11322)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11309)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22420)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3756)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5889)
```

```
The above error occurred in the <Connect(Quiz)> component:

TypeError: #<Object> is not a constructor
    at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:483522:29)
    at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:483724:29)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:483157:30)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:482777:35)
    at App
    at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:480393:20)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

> FYI I'm using React js not React-Native

Comment: No, I'm using React. I have mentioned in my question itself

Comment: React native? <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60471786/react-native-redux-object-is-not-a-constructor-evaluating-new-ctorprops-con>

Comment: But my application is not react-native, it's reactjs